# Detect splash screen exit on Unity Android/Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I've created an Eclipse project based on a Vuforia/Unity project by following the instructions [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extending-unity-android-activity-and-adding-custom-views-eclipse). That's up and running.

I am adding a button to my main activity, extends from QCARPlayerActivity. That also works, however, the button sits on top of the Unity player as the Unity splash screen plays.

Is there any way to detect when the Unity splash screen exits so I don't have controls in place before the scene loads?

**UPDATE 3/18/13**

I've added a static boolean to my main activity in Eclipse to track splash screen completion and modified the code that adds the controls to watch the boolean.

MainActivity.java

```
public static boolean splashComplete = false;
private View mControlViewContainer = null; // initialized in onCreate

class QCARViewFinderTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!QCAR.isInitialized()) return; //wait for QCAR init
//search for QCAR view if it hasn't been found
                if (mQCARView == null)
                {
                    View rootView = MainActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                    QCARUnityPlayer qcarView = findQCARView(rootView);
                    if (qcarView != null) {
                        mQCARParentView = (ViewGroup)(qcarView.getParent());
                        mQCARView = qcarView;
                    }
                }                       

                // add controls if QCAR view is located and the splash sequence is complete
                if(mQCARView != null && splashComplete && mControlViewContainer != null){
                    mQCARParentView.addView(mControlViewContainer);
                    mViewFinderTimer.cancel();
                    mViewFinderTimer = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In Unity I created a simple script to set the static boolean in Java and attached it to the Vuforia ARCamera

SplashExit.js

```
function Start () {
    var mainActivity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.example.app.MainActivity");
    mainActivity.SetStatic.("splashComplete",true);
}
```

This works fairly well in a project with a simple scene. My controls seem to load on splash exit. When I use this method with a more complicated scene, however, the controls come up a second or so before the splash screen disappears.

Is there a better place to attach my Unity script, or a better method within the script, that will more accurately reflect when the splash sequence has exited? Perhaps Jerdak's suggestion in the comments?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: I assume this is Unity basic with a Unity iOS license? Barring a clean method, could you create an empty level w/ a single script that calls Application.LoadLevel to load your actual level? I can't recall if the Splash shows between all level loads or just when you start the app.

Comment: @Jerdak It's Unity Pro with Unity Android license. I may not be following, but I'm not sure how I can use this method to signal my wrapper activity when the splash sequence has completed.

Comment: @JasonGeorge It's been awhile since I used my mobile license but on PC the splash is only displayed before the first level load, hence my comment about creating a dummy level.  But if all you are looking for is a place to trigger splashComplete, how about [OnLevelWasLoaded()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html).

Comment: @Jerdak I tried OnLevelWasLoaded, but it didn't seem to trigger. Adding a yield prior to setting my splashComplete variable did the trick. It seems to stall the routine until the 1st frame has had a chance to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a yield statement did the trick. Full solution follows.

SplashExit.js should be attached to the ARCamera Game object in Unity. The start method will stall until the scene has loaded up, then set splashComplete to true in MainActivity.java.

As the timer in MainActivity.java repeatedly calls the run method of QCARViewFinderTask, the control view will be added to the Unity Player parent view as splashComplete transitions to true.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends QCARPlayerActivity {
    private QCARUnityPlayer mQCARView = null;
    private ViewGroup mQCARParentView = null;
    private Timer mViewFinderTimer = null;
    private View mControlViewContainer = null;

    public static boolean splashComplete = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mControlViewContainer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.control_layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mQCARView == null) {
            //search the QCAR view
            mViewFinderTimer = new Timer();
            mViewFinderTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new QCARViewFinderTask(), 1000, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mViewFinderTimer != null) {
            mViewFinderTimer.cancel();
            mViewFinderTimer = null;
        }
    }

    class QCARViewFinderTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (!QCAR.isInitialized()) return; //wait for QCAR init

                    //search for QCAR view if it hasn't been found
                    if (mQCARView == null)
                    {
                        View rootView = MainActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                        QCARUnityPlayer qcarView = findQCARView(rootView);
                        if (qcarView != null) {
                            mQCARParentView = (ViewGroup)(qcarView.getParent());
                            mQCARView = qcarView;
                        }
                    }                       

                    // add controls if QCAR view is located and the splash sequence is complete
                    if(mQCARView != null && splashComplete && mControlViewContainer != null){
                        mQCARParentView.addView(mControlViewContainer);
                        mViewFinderTimer.cancel();
                        mViewFinderTimer = null;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private QCARUnityPlayer findQCARView(View view) {
            if (view instanceof QCARUnityPlayer) {
                return (QCARUnityPlayer)view;
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
                for (int i = 0; i
```

SplashExit.js

```
function Start () {
    yield; // wait for the scene to fully load
    // Note that com.example.app.MainActivity should be updated to match your bundle identifier and class names
    var mainActivity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.example.app.MainActivity");
    mainActivity.SetStatic.("splashComplete",true);
}
```