# Unity Android black screen

Tags: android, screen, unity-game-engine, loading

When running a build, Unity loads as usual but then fades into the scene from black. There is a delay before the black screen begins to fade, but the game is already running. I catch the menu animation halfway finished by the time the screen fades and on other devices it fades so late that the animation is entirely finished.

I couldn't find any variable that would indicate Unity is finished doing its thing, so I'm not sure what I can do besides add a pause to the beginning of the program. I'm instantiating several things, including dealing with a dynamic mesh, so I would understand it being maybe a bit late, but I see the same behavior in a new project as well.

I'm relatively new to Unity, so there might just be some setting I don't know about or something similar that might be causing this. Has anyone had a similar issue, or know what may be causing this?

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281513/detect-splash-screen-exit-on-unity-android-eclipse-project)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do anything for me. I'm inclined to believe what I'm experiencing is a Unity feature meant to make the transition smoother, and that there isn't really a way to reference that from within the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with untiy on Mac OS X. When I build my apps using unity on Windows, there is no fade-in effect in the beginning of the game, but after I port it to unity on Mac OS X, the fade-in effects appears. I assume you are using Mac OS X, try to build your app on windows, if thats the case. And, yes. There is no work around for this on Mac, I don't know why thay put this effect for Mac version.